# Automating Variations

Tags: automation

So I don't know if this is the right place to ask this but long story short I've been looking to get into programming and I'd like my first project to be automating our inventory counting process at my dealership.

After we count the stock we have to punch in the numbers into our system and see if it gives us any variations (Ex. There should be 3 bolts instead of 2)

What i wanna do is find a way to simply upload photos of the papers and have it recognize the part number and input the count numbers itself

Is that possible? And if so where would i begin i appreciate any resources you can point me too or examples and once again if this is the wrong place for this sorry!

[image: Here's what the pages look like]

Comment: In what Language do you want to code? And getting an Input from an Image is not an easy task ... not for someone who is just starting to learn how to code. It is possible ofc! Counting the Stock and inputting those numbers by hand and then let the system compare your input with the stock that should be there, would be a bit easier for the start.

Comment: Python would be my preference as i do have some experience with that. The way you described is how we currently do it but with the amount of stock we have the process sometimes takes up to 3 hours. I know this wasn't an easy task from the beginning but i want to try and learn how. Although I also wouldn't mind just using an app to type in the numbers instead of writing them on paper i imagine writing it into an app would be easier to translate that data onto our inventory count system? I have some experience with Android development as well but for very basic apps.

Comment: If you want to use an app to type in the numbers you need to compare your input with the count of the system. I guess your inventory System is some kind of database? If yes, you can connect to the data base from your app and let the app compare your input with the values stored at your Inventory Database.

Comment: And how would i go about doing that? Through an API correct?

Comment: Yes, if your Database is somehow accessible through an API